# Ошибка "Trust anchor for certification path not found" при запросе(android)

Tags: android, android-studio

возникла проблема, при отправке запроса на сервер. Как я понял это связано с сертификатом сайта и нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы приложение при запросе доверяло любому сертификату сайта. Подскажите, как это можно эффективно реализовать, буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.
Вот мой код:

```
public void sendPost() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            String boundary =  "*****";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                    jsonParam.put("username", EText_login);
                    jsonParam.put("password", EText_password);
                    Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                    os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());



                    os.flush();
                    os.close();

                    Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                    Log.i("MSG" , conn.getRequestMethod());

                    String resultJson = "";
                    InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }

                    resultJson = buffer.toString();
                    dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                    globalvariables.ClientToken = dataJsonObj.getString("token");


                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, globalvariables.ClientToken);


                    conn.disconnect();



                    Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                    Log.i("MSG" , String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                    if (globalvariables.ClientToken != "") {
                        saveText();
                        globalvariables.LogIn_test = 1;
                        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
                        fragment3 frag3 = new fragment3();
                        FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fTrans.replace(R.id.frgmCont, frag3);
                        fTrans.commit();
                    }
                    else{
                        globalvariables.LogIn_test = 2;
                    }

                    //jsonParam2.put("photo", toBase64(bitmap));
                    //jsonParam2.put("collect", "32221");
                    //jsonParam2.put("user_comment", "3222");
                    //DataOutputStream os3 = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                    //os3.writeBytes(jsonParam2.toString());
                    //os3.flush();
                    //os3.close();


                    conn.disconnect();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
```

Ошибка:

> 8-02 23:10:19.935 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found. 08-02 23:10:19.936
>   26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235) 08-02
>   23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199) 08-02
>   23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172) 08-02
>   23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.jone1.graciaonline.fragment1$3.run(fragment1.java:149)
>   08-02 23:10:19.936 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760) 08-02
>   23:10:19.937 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found. 08-02 23:10:19.937
>   26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:563)
>   08-02 23:10:19.937 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:444)
>   08-02 23:10:19.937 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
>   08-02 23:10:19.937 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
>   08-02 23:10:19.937 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
>   08-02 23:10:19.938 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
>   08-02 23:10:19.938 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
>   08-02 23:10:19.938 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
>   08-02 23:10:19.938 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
>   08-02 23:10:19.938 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>   08-02 23:10:19.938 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
>   08-02 23:10:19.938 26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   W/System.err:     ... 14 more 08-02 23:10:19.939
>   26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer W/System.err: Caused
>   by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found. 08-02 23:10:19.939
>   26756-14149/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer W/System.err:     ... 25
>   more

Comment: мб вам поможет тоже https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев, я находил этот ответ, но как я понял эту проблему там решают со стороны сервера или я не прав?

Comment: да, на самом деле - это недосмотр авторов сайта, т.к. гугл вычеркнул их из списка доверительных ресурсов. Но обойти это придется вам, если вы хотите именно этот ресурс показывать

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев, а как это можно реализовать? Я просто далеко не сказать, что опытен в этом :D

Comment: я тоже)) .....................

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев :D

Comment: По ссылке находится решение для Андроидов 4 и 5. Применено на Retrofit. К сожалению, Glide пока не даёт скачивать изображения на них.